# Server returns binary data in HTML

Tags: apache, plone

I have a Plone website, running ZEO, pound and apache.
Sometimes, I have this returned :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <p>
            �ÿÍKoÛ0ïù   àØy÷²ìuS/,3VYrõH¿~ínÒ&#13;;thàÀDJúHF¯þµÆv{Ð](g"ðkQÊÜIn`Öbwk©¸÷X~+÷,êm5Îy®3n³fXÎñ#(rGbÄJ&#13;7¨=(ÓBVA)ÈÐs©Ü,4-÷Òh(-n¤    N=ÀÄEp'ý¼åS.n.:[¦Û`üe²6&amp;4CòÈVklÊ0odi*3Á÷kL0Ï]rMú£þ(é×/Fñ,&amp;ArýímrÒ¥±¸kSSI·Fõ²(©ÆÃ¤Æ¤1Bò+v8O{ÿõ   *iþíÃM&amp;ã®¬Å¬0YPX1¢ÞHktD»¾ÎvÑöÌÏ0ß©uÌhô5/(ùÊ£e¤à{çÕ{ÏÄå/·â'9µÚ45+¹'Ó2Ö¬öÏÃ£ó¶1G;nvöça¯ ÛþdQ  í¨õ¡ôÕvSÐmëîî«ikÞþ0¦§ÅÙ%¬àJÛA   8;ß'µèÕTûÔ*Î0ß·í°}÷gî`CGAJÙT3Ç7¸ÐÙ'ôËJB¢97ÆÑëkôºã;:"èxW÷    ë°)vq²µâu
            ð×÷ïÆ}J¾Aîû÷g36Ô¹H:ÉÒh/"Og§sr·eí± ÏÓ¶kçrI'ÅòÙÈ¤¿h9}zgÈ¸çéö#þæ~Ó52Áý`:fiBqçàÊÒi#¼_&gt;^)£1þ¤¸ù¬©¸)ö§1ê®^§÷Fx   
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Instead of a correct HTML.

Any clues?

Comment: That is correct HTML.. The body contains grabage text, but that is correct HTML.

Comment: Otherwise, there is no way we can diagnose this. Break this down by a) reproducing it, b) seeing if it occurs at the Apache, Pound, or Plone level.

Comment: Yeah, that is "correct" HTML, but not the one expected ;)

Comment: It 'smells' like some form of compression is being applied then wrapped by another layer as if it needs to fill a template slot.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to remove mod_deflate from apache...

Comment: ok, so it seems that it come's from Plone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly found from where it came.

Analysing the logs, I found out that every time I've got this behavior I have a `ConflictError: database conflict error (oid 0x0545db, class Products.CMFPlone.QuickInstallerTool.QuickInstallerTool)`

See here [the full traceback](http://pastebin.com/493PsTKS)

After invastigating where I use the QuickInstallerTool in my code, I found that I use it in a browser view method :

```py
def isMB(self):
    """ Sommes-nous dans une marque blanche ? """
    qi = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_quickinstaller')
    prods = qi.listInstallableProducts(skipInstalled=False)

    for prod in prods:
        if (prod['id'] == 'theme.marqueBlanche') and (prod['status'] == 'installed'):
            return True
```

To avoid the calculation every time the methode is called, I have cached it like this :

```py
def cache_isMB(method,self,plonesite):
    return (plonesite, time() // (3600 * 3660))

@ram.cache(cache_isMB)
def isMB(self, plonesite):
    """ Sommes-nous dans une marque blanche ? """
    qi = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_quickinstaller')
    prods = qi.listInstallableProducts(skipInstalled=False)

    for prod in prods:
        if (prod['id'] == 'theme.marqueBlanche') and (prod['status'] == 'installed'):
            return True
```

The plonesite argument is the id of the Plone instance.

What I didn't figure out, is why is there a write when listing all installable products ?

Comment: The write sounds like a bug... there was some addon management changes in Plone 4.x which might have fixed extra writes on startup. To inspect it:http://developer.plone.org/persistency/transactions.html#viewing-transaction-content-and-debugging-transactions